# Remove Quotes from Inside of Formula VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am looking to autofill an equation to an entire row.

The problem I am facing is when the equation autofills it puts quotes around the cell reference. When it returns the equation the cell reads =DATEVALUE("E2").

Any tips on how to remove the "" from E2?

Here is my equation below.

Thanks,

Rebecca

```
Sub formula()

Dim lastRowF As Long


    lastRowF = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEVALUE(E2)"
    Range("F2").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F" & lastRowF)
    'Range("F2:F248225").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Change `.FormulaR1C1` to just `.Formula`.  Or use the `R1C1` ref style, `.FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEVALUE(RC5)` for an absolute reference, or `...RC[-1]` for a relative one.

Comment: `Range("F2").Formula = "=DATEVALUE(E2)"` Much simpler

Answer (score 4):

1. You are doing `FormulaR1C1` and `E2` is in `A1` format. R1C1 is relative to the cell in which the formula is being placed, so in this instance we want to move one column to the left.  `RC[-1]`. Or as stated in the comments, change to `.Formula` which is A1 based.
2. Do not use `Select`.  See here for more info on avoiding that trap: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)
3. No need for fill down, just assign the formula to all the cells at the same time.  Excel will adjust the row number automatically as they are relative and not absolute.

So do this:

```
Sub formula()

Dim lastRowF As Long

With ActiveSheet    
    lastRowF = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("F2:F" & lastRowF).FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEVALUE(RC[-1])"
    .Range("F2:F" & lastRowF).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
End with

End Sub
```

If you want to use A1 style:

```
Sub formula()

Dim lastRowF As Long

With ActiveSheet    
    lastRowF = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("F2:F" & lastRowF).Formula = "=DATEVALUE(E2)"
    .Range("F2:F" & lastRowF).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
End with

End Sub
```